# Overriding CSS on github pages using slate theme?

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to override the "forkme" banner on my github.io page to get a better understanding of how Jekyll, HTML, CSSand GitHub works.

For that purpose, I created my `./assets/css/style.css` file as mentioned in the readme of the official documentation on how to customize the CSS of the officially supported GitHub themes. I added the following CSS to it:

```
#forkme_banner { display: none; }
```

However, no luck, the banner doesn't disappear. Even adding fictitious elements to the CSS file like `#test {testing: testtest;}` doesn't add the line to my CSS file.

Comment: Repository url please.

Comment: https://github.com/usefuljapanese/lex/blob/gh-pages/assets/css/style.css

Comment: @DavidJacquel https://github.com/usefuljapanese/lex/blob/gh-pages/assets/css/style.css

Comment: Is it just sample code from usefuljapanese.github.io repo or are you hosting your css in lex repository ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel it is not sample code, it is supposed to be the real thing which renders to www.l-ex.tokyo...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

rename assets/css/**style.css** to **style.scss**
and change your scss code to :

```
---
---
@import "{{ site.theme }}";
#footer_wrap {display: none;}
#forkme_banner {display: none;}
#downloads {display: none;}
#whocares {haha: hehe;}
```

Comment: I tried, that, but no luck. I am assuming that jekyll is not rebuilding for some reason, I will give github some time, maybe there is a queue delay. However, I noticed you recommend "style.scss" while the documentation specifies "style.css". Also, you remove one newline character after the header, while the documentation inserts a newline between header and the first @import statement:

Comment: Ah, I get an error now on my settings page for the repo: Your site is having problems building: Your SCSS file assets/css/style.scss has an error on line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: . Load path: /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-theme-slate-0.0.3/_sass. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-sass-or-scss.

Comment: unfortunately installing jekyll to further troubleshoot is not an option for me at this moment as the article suggests... any other ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/usefuljapanese/lex/blob/gh-pages/assets/css/style.scss

Comment: It seems that `@import "{{ site.theme }}";` was working locally but not on github pages. 

It now seem to work (see my fork [here][1] and result [here][2]).

Can you try to push a small commit to force regeneration and see if it works.

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! Btw I don't see any links you referenced as [1] or [2], I can only see text but nothing to click on. Not that I need to see as it works now, just letting you know. THANKS a lot!!!

Comment: David's original answer worked for me. I'm trying to do the exact same thing: deploy a Jekyll blog to GH pages with the slate theme, but hide the 'View On Github' banner. Note that David's code should go in `/assets/css/style.scss`, not in `/_site/`, then once you've added the `.scss` file run `jekyll build` and commit everything before pushing to GH.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost thing is that the CSS changes takes time to update because it will be cached at their servers.
It usually takes 15-45 minutes for me but for few, it is taking 3 hours. I think it depends on the server location that Github pages are hosed if I am not wrong.

Coming to issue

```
`./assets/css/style.css

 // change to 

./assets/css/style.scss`
```

it should be changed to .scss.

Another troubleshoot that I encountered is

```
---
---
@import "{{ site.theme }}";
/* "{{ site.theme }}" = Your theme name */
/* Eg: @import 'jekyll-theme-cayman'; */

/* Your css rules goes after this */
.page-header {
    background: #191c20;
}
```